# How to use Card Storage with Global Payments Ecommerce HPP?

Tags: realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

I have the following payment form that I setup:

```
<form id="ccform" action="https://hpp.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay" method="post" target="output_frame">

  <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" id="MERCHANT_ID" value="Merchant ID">
  <input type="hidden" name="ACCOUNT" id="ACCOUNT" value="internet">
  <input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" id="ORDER_ID" value="20180518231046JP">
  <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" id="CURRENCY" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" id="AMOUNT" value="500">
  <input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" id="TIMESTAMP" value="20180518231046">
  <input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" id="SHA1HASH" value="8596447e0229c2f7216bca240d6a291f9cec5e14">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_POST_RESPONSE" id="HPP_POST_RESPONSE" value="correctWebsiteButRemoved">
  <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_VERSION" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="CARD_STORAGE_ENABLE" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="OFFER_SAVE_CARD" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="PAYER_EXIST" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="PAYER_REF" id="PAYER_REF" value="asdahsioda">
  <input type="hidden" name="PMT_REF" id="PMT_REF" value="20180518231046JP-asdasda">

  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME" value="First">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CUSTOMER_LASTNAME" value="Last">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_LANG" value="DE">
  <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value="http://www.google.ie">

  <input type="submit" value="Proceed to secure server" id="SUBMITBTN">
</form>
```

I was trying to get the card storage process to work with Realex. I just can't get it work. It does not reply with the correct values that I would expect based on the documentation: https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/hpp/card-storage-and-management/create-payer-and-store-card

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. Your request POST looks correct, can you please check with a member of our Support Team that Card Storage through the HPP is enabled on your account? It is not enabled by default.

Comment: I've got it working, thanks for your help. I have another question. For the initial card storage, it is possible to provide a payment reference that then references the card. When I look at the example for the recurring card storage and a payer wants to add another card, it is not possible. Is there a way to provide payment references (PMT_REF) for additional cards?

Comment: Hello, yes it is possible. If you supply a PMT_REF in addition to HPP_SELECT_STORED_CARD, if the customer chooses to store a new card it will be stored using the PMT_REF you supplied.